# Calculate Average using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to PIG and want to calculate Average of my one column data that looks like

0
10.1
20.1
30
40
50
60
70
80.1

I wrote this pig script

```
dividends = load 'myfile.txt' as (A);
dump dividends
grouped   = group dividends by A;
avg       = foreach grouped generate AVG(grouped.A);
dump avg
```

It parses data as

(0)
(10.1)
(20.1)
(30)
(40)
(50)
(60)
(70)
(80.1)

but gives this error for average

```
2013-03-04 15:10:58,289 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<file try.pig, line 4, column 41> Invalid scalar projection: grouped
Details at logfile: /Users/PreetiGupta/Documents/CMPS290S/project/pig_1362438645642.log
```

ANY IDEA

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `AVG` built in function takes a bag as an input. In your `group` statement, you are currently grouping elements by the value of `A`, but what you really want to do is group all the elements into one bag.

Pig's `GROUP ALL` is what you want to use:

```
dividends = load 'myfile.txt' as (A);
dump dividends
grouped   = group dividends all;
avg       = foreach grouped generate AVG(dividends.A);
dump avg
```

Answer (score 5):

The below will work for calculating average:

```
dividends = load 'myfile.txt' as (A);
grouped   = GROUP dividends all;
avg       = foreach grouped generate AVG(dividends);
dump avg
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the original data variable name instead of using a group variable. In `FOREACH` line, I am using `AVG(dividends.A)` instead of `AVG(grouped.A)`. Here is the solution script:

```
dividends = load 'myfile.txt' as (A);
dump dividends

grouped   = group dividends by A;
avg = foreach grouped generate AVG(dividends.A);
dump avg
```